# JPA - An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration

Tags: java, jpa

I wonder why I got "An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration." error when I don't have alias.
Seems like I solved by problem when I added alias to the table.

Code with problem:

```
List result = entityManager.createQuery( "from Rental", Rental.class ).getResultList();
```

Solution:

```
List result = entityManager.createQuery( "from Rental r", Rental.class ).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should make a distinction between `HQL` (Hibernate Query Language) and `JPQL` (Java Persistence Query Language). As long as your provider is Hibernate you will see no difference, but you have to remember that correct `JPQL` query consists of `SELECT` keyword. [Here's](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2710) explanation of this differences.

Going back to you question - it is `JPQL` requirement to define alias for each Entity table.